# How do I trigger a next on an observable for the purposes of testing?

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I have an observable

```
const onLoad = fromEvent(iframeElement, 'load')
```

When testing, what's the best strategy to trigger it?

```
it('should run', () => {
    onLoad.next()??
})
```

Comment: While testing it's considered best practice to mimic the application's behavior as realistic as possible. So, I would call the method in the unit test and subscribe to it. Or use a Spy.

Comment: I think you should be actually mocking `iframeElement`

Answer (score 0):

Stub your onLoad with `subject`

```
const onLoad = new Subject()

onLoad.next()
```